# Playing audio using a binary stream in server in Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio

I am using Node js for server code and Javascript for client side. In the server side, I have a generated binary stream which represent some audio in wav format. and I have the capability of piping it to a write stream, for example: supposing that the binary stream name is bs: `bs.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('fileName.wav'))`.

I want to play the audio immediately after the binary stream is generated or after it has been written to the write stream. I tried some method which uses speaker module in node js, but whenever I work with the speaker module it gives me this error: fatal error: alsa/asoundlib.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated. and when I searched for how to eliminate this error, I found only one workaround which involves using this command: `sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev`, and the problem is that it is a linux command and I am working on windows.

What is the simplest way by which I can play this audio ? (either through the server or through the client)

Note: I use socket.io for sending data between client and server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simplest would probably to load `fileName.wav` directly in the browser from an HTMLAudioElement, if you really want to use a bytestream, then have a look at [MSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource)

Comment: Note that this file is on server, I tried to send it to the client using delivery module but there is something wrong and the file is not sent, what way do you suggest me to use to send the file from the server to the client ?

Comment: `new Audio('pathToFileOnServer/fileName.wav')`

Comment: well, that worked finally. I had problems with the paths in this case (and didn't notice that I had these problems), but now figured out the actual paths that I had to use after some trials. thank you for pointing this out to me !